# How to submit form with validation in javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hi created php page with input form and validation.
The problem is that when i click on submit the validation works but the form is not submitted... Anyone can help me to understand where is the problem?

[https://jsfiddle.net/892wm47t/][1]

Comment: where is the validation code (javascript)?

Comment: If you want the data to be delivered to `submitted.php` then why not use the `<form method="post" action="submitted.php"` attribute to do it

Comment: Now you have thrown away the HTML and PHP you had originally

Comment: because when i click on submit it doesn't validate...

Comment: the problem is that here i cannot paste all the code... it says that it's too much code...

Comment: @developmentcpm2022 – SO expects you to provide a [mcve]; not ask people to debug entire large applications for you.

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` stops the submission from completing. You're calling it on every attempt to submit the form.

You need to call it **conditionally**; only when the validation reports a problem.

Comment: this platform is incredbile impossible to add a full case: have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/892wm47t/

Comment: @developmentcpm2022 — That seems to be the same code. You don't seem to have implemented this answer at all.

Comment: in the jfiddle file you can see all the replicated code.. so all completed code

Comment: What's your point? This answer is still what you need to do.